Double pole 15 only provides 1 leg for heater, other leg comes from separate single pole 15
I’m only getting power from 1 leg of the double pole circuit. So to get 240v for heater I have to turn on a separate circuit, single pole 15. Could one of the breakers have failed, and someone’s solution was to add a circuit, not replace the breaker?

Certainly possible. NOT desirable since circuit remains hot after first breaker blows...

It sounds likely.  Can you carefully trace the wires?

My crystal ball sees a new double pole breaker in your future.

A picture of the panel showing the relevant breakers would be very helpful.

A damaged, only one side working, double pole breaker should be replaced yesterday.  You have no way of knowing if it will trip or turn off if needed.

Not to mention the handles aren't tied. Pictures please of this nonsense so we can spot if there's any other shenanigans going on. With the panel cover off too if at all possible.

Open the panel and see if the black and white wires from the one heater cable go to the two different breakers in question, and the other leg of the two-pole one has nothing connected.
